# Restriction for post to the map display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

i'm currently building a web app, and I encounters some problems. 
I want the map display posts that are pushed (so push == true). For that, i'd try a lot of conditions, but it's never working. I feel I am not far from the goal, but for now, the map no reference points.

posts controller :

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
  
    @posts = Post.all.order("push_updated_at DESC")
  if @posts.push == true
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@posts) do |post, marker|
    marker.lat post.latitude
    marker.lng post.longitude
  end

end
end  


  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end


  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        @post.update(push: false)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]) 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :title, :description, :image, :push, :push_updated_at, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
    end

    def owned_post  
  unless current_user == @post.user
    flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end  

end
```

views/posts/index :

```html
<div class="title text-center">
  <h1>Alors ? On mange quoi ?</h1>
</div>

<br>


<%= render 'map' %>

<%= render 'post' %>
```

& views/posts/map :

```html
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script> 
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->



<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

So if you have any suggestions about that, you're welcome !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this stage you should create a `scope` on model `Post`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :push, ->{ where(push: true).order("push_updated_at DESC") }
end
```

and then in controller

```
def index
 @posts = Post.push #this will fetch the post with push true and sort it
 @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@posts) do |post, marker|
 #rest of your code
end
```